# Make simple table from data frame using formula

Tags: r

I've got a large dataframe with 72 rows and 72 columns. All are numbers. I just want to make a table with the sum of the the first row multiplied by the sum of the first column and so on and so forth. So for example, if this is my df

```
x0 <- c(0,0,11,0)
x0.1 <- c(0,251,0,0)
x0.2 <- c(0,495,0,0)
x0.4 <- c(0,0,0,6)
df <- data.frame(x0,x0.1,x0.2,x0.4)
```

I want my table to look something like this

```
1 0
2 124911
3 5445
4 36
```

Comment: Isn't the second value meant to be `187246` ?

Answer (score 1):

Would you be looking for:

```
rowSums(df)*colSums(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using sapply:

```
sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i){sum(df[i,]*sum(df[,i]))})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  unite(x, c(x0, x0.1, x0.2, x0.4), sep = "") %>% 
  mutate(x = sub("^0+(?!$)", "", x, perl=TRUE))
```

```
        x
1       0
2 2514950
3   11000
4       6
```